# Instance of Continuum Hypothesis implying cardinal inequality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm currently trying to solve Exercise 5.27 of Jech's *Set Theory (3rd Millennium ed.)*, viz:

> If $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$, then $\aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0} \ne \aleph_{\omega_1}$.

The presumption is saying that there is no cardinal between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$ but I fail to see how this can be employed in this "negative computation" of $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf} \kappa}$ with $\kappa = \aleph_\omega$.

Any hints are much appreciated; I suspect that the right pointer will enable me to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that for $\alpha<\omega_1$ $\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_1}=
\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_0}\cdot 2^{\aleph_1}$; exercise $5.19$ of the book, and the assumption $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$to conclude $\aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_1}$, then use [König's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29#K.C3.B6nig.27s_theorem_and_cofinality).

Comment: Thanks. It took me a few moments to figure out the last bit but I've got it now. I guess I was put off by the premise being very strong; we only actually used $2^{\aleph_1} < \aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin you're welcome